# In the Django admin page, when creating a new instance of a model, is there a way to disallow certain foreign key instances from appearing as choices?

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have three models: Restaurant, MenuCategory(breakfast, lunch, etc.), and FoodItem. FoodItem has two foreign key fields, one to Restaurant, and the other to MenuCategory. MenuCategory has one foreign key field, to Restaurant.

When I try to create a new FoodItem via the Django admin page, I am asked to select a Restaurant, and MenuCategory, and some other unrelated fields such as the name of the food or the description. However, when I look through the choices for MenuCategory, I can see every possible MenuCategory that exists, even those that do not belong to the Restaurant that I have currently chosen for the FoodItem about to be created.

When I am making a new FoodItem, is there a way to get the admin page to only display the MenuCategories that belong to the current Restaurant I have selected?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to restrict the queryset used in dropdown field.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset

I've also pasted the docs here.

> ModelAdmin.get_queryset(request)
>
> The get_queryset method on a ModelAdmin returns a QuerySet of all
>   model instances that can be edited by the admin site. One use case for
>   overriding this method is to show objects owned by the logged-in user:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(author=request.user)
```

Essentially you would just restrict to the that you want to display only.

Comment: Is there any way to access what has currently been selected though? Because this approach filters the queryset based on the user, which is already known. Since I am making the FoodItem all in one go, I would have to first specify the restaurant, and then I would want only the relevant menu categories to appear.